# OpenShift Node.js WebSocket server connection issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I am trying to connect to my server running on OpenShift using WebSockets, but no matter how I configure it, nothing seems to go through. I've tried connecting ports `8000`, `8080`, and `80` with binding to `8000` and `8080`, but nothing gets through.

My client attempts to connect:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://trserve-trserver.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com:8000');
connection.onopen = function() {
  window.alert("Connected!");
};
```

But `"Connected"` never pops up in an alert window. On the server side:

```
var webSocketsServerPort = process.env.PORT ||
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var webSocketIP = process.env.IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0';
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {});
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, webSocketIP, function() {
  console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " +
    webSocketsServerPort);
});
var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
  httpServer: server
});
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + '.');
```

The server prints:

```
"The server is listening on port 8080"
```

but never list anything with Connection from the origin.

Comment: Maybe you have some origin issue. Try to allow any origin.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: `var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);` refer this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

Comment: I am not able to figure out what is the problem wihtout any error log. have you configured any logger? If so, please put log here too.

Comment: One more thing is, can you please clarify which package you are using on server side or same as on client side?

Comment: I am using the same package on the server side as the client side.  I'm still relatively new to OpenScript and NodeJS, so I haven't explicitly coded in a logger besides the console.logs you see in the code.  I enabled both readiness and liveliness probes and they both seem to have passed (with TCP connection on port 8080.)

Comment: If you are using OpenShift NodeJS S2I, you should listen on 0.0.0.0 and port 8080 in the container. From outside of the cluster you would access using the hostname of the route and port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS if enabled. WebSockets also go via port 80/443. There is no separate WebSocket port like with older OpenShift 2.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I believe I am listening on 0.0.0.0 and 8080 on the server (see server code above).  Connecting to ws://trserve-trserver.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com:80 and ws://trserve-trserver.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com:443 do not work

Comment: Has your code by chance been set up to expect that separate sockets are used for http and ws? Do you need to change it so they coexist on the same socket?

Answer (score 0):

**Client side:**

**Example 1:** Using the [W3C WebSocket API](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/).

```
var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;

var client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');

client.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Connection Error');
};

client.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
};
```

**Example 2:**

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');
```

**Server side:**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
     if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
          request.reject();
     }
     return;
}

var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
});
```

Source: [WebSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

Hope, this may help you. You just need to go step by step. Most important is to allow origin from backend from where client request is coming.

Comment: None of these seemed to make a difference.  What's interesting is that absolutely no callbacks are being handled, almost like it was silently crashing on connection attempt.  I haven't been able to find any documentation so far about this